# Update store based on user input data in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I have experience working with hooks but not with class based components and redux.

I have a wizard form and Page1 has *firstName* and *lastName* input fields. A *next* button which takes to Page2 and acts as submit if necessary.

#### What I expect?

Whenever user inputs some value in one of the field, it should update the redux store. (I'm not sure if I should update store directly on `onChange` event of the input field **OR** store it in state first and then update store on `onSubmit`)

#### UPDATE:

Right now, this code is not working. Whenever I type 1st character in firstName input field, its property from the store gets undefined.

```
// store.js FILE
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  signUpCounterPage: reducer1,
  user: reducer2, 
});

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(logger))
);


// Types.js FILE
export const UPDATE_FIRSTNAME = "UPDATE_FIRSTNAME";
export const UPDATE_LASTNAME = "UPDATE_LASTNAME";
export const UPDATE_ADDRESS = "UPDATE_ADDRESS";
export const UPDATE_APT_UNIT = "UPDATE_APT_UNIT";
// --------------------------

// Actions.js FILE
export const updateFirstName = (action) => ({
  type: UPDATE_FIRSTNAME,
  ...action,
});

export const updateLastName = (action) => ({
  type: UPDATE_LASTNAME,
  action,
});

export const updateAddress = (action) => ({
  type: UPDATE_ADDRESS,
  action,
});

export const updateAptUnit = (action) => ({
  type: UPDATE_APT_UNIT,
  action,
});
// --------------------------


// reducer2.js FILE
const initialState = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  address: "",
  aptUnit: "",
};

const signupUserReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_FIRSTNAME:
      return { ...state, firstName: action.value };
    case UPDATE_LASTNAME:
      return { ...state, lastName: action.value };
    case UPDATE_ADDRESS:
      return { ...state, address: action.value };
    case UPDATE_APT_UNIT:
      return { ...state, aptUnit: action.value };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
// --------------------------


// Page1.js FILE
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      firstName: state.firstName,
    });
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, param) => ({
      updateFirstName: () => dispatch(updateFirstName(param.value)),
    });

    class Page1 extends Component {
      state = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
      };
      render() {
        const {
          nextPage,
          firstName,
          updateFirstName
        } = this.props;
        return ( <
          div className = "onboarding-page d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" >
          <
          div className = "d-flex flex-column align-items-center" >
          <
          Form className = "d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" >
          <
          Form.Row >
          <
          Form.Group as = {
            Col
          }
          controlId = "formGridFirstName" >
          <
          Form.Control type = "text"
          placeholder = "Enter First Name"
          value = {
            firstName
          }
          onChange = {
            (e) => updateFirstName({
              value: e.target.value
            })
          }
          />  <
          /Form.Group>

          <
          Form.Group as = {
            Col
          }
          controlId = "formGridLastName" >
          <
          Form.Control type = "text"
          placeholder = "Enter Last Name"
          value={lastName}
          onChange={(e) => updateLastName({ value: e.target.value })}
          /
          >
          <
          /Form.Group> < /
          Form.Row > <
          Form.Group className = "d-flex justify-content-center" >
          <
          Button variant = "primary"
          size = "medium"
          onClick = {
            nextPage
          } >
          Next < /
          Button > <
          /Form.Group> < /
          Form > <
          /div> < /
          div >
        );
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Page1);
```

Comment: You can update store directly using onChange without creating any internel state

Comment: thanks. but right now this code is not working. whenever I type 1st character in firstName input field, its property from the store gets undefined.

Comment: Can you please share your code in code sandbox??

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-sunset-df94d

Comment: `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateFirstName: (param) => dispatch(updateFirstName(param)),
  updateLastName: (param) => dispatch(updateLastName(param))
})`

Comment: at this part of the section, you were doing a mistake you can replace this with your one

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash it works. You are a life saver!!!! submit the answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234734/discussion-between-dhruvil21-04-and-muhammad-bilal-bangash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ updateFirstName: (param) => dispatch(updateFirstName(param)), updateLastName: (param) => dispatch(updateLastName(param)) })
```

Please update your mapDispatchToProps function, there you are doing small mistake